# Syntax error when making multiple OR conditionals on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I make a conditional on jQuery that specifies to make something if an input OR a select list is empty, jQuery works fine:

```
if((($('input[name=su_name]').val())=="") || ($('select[name=su_family]').val())=="0")
{...}
```

But when I try to make it check 3 fields (if one, or the other, or the other is empty), I have a syntax error focusing the second "||". Is it not possible to set two "||" (OR) on the same conditional? This does **not** work:

```
if((($('input[name=su_name]').val())=="") || ($('select[name=su_family]').val())=="0") || ($('input[name=su_abbrev]').val())=="")
{...}
```

Comment: You don't balance the parenthesis. Try formatting your code correctly before you ask a question, this might solve it.

Comment: In the 2nd code example the 2nd comparison compares with `"0"` is that a bug?

Comment: No it is not Doge, select first value is 0 ("select"), one of the other options must be selected not that one. Solved.

Comment: Totally right @dystroy, as the two conditionals worked didn't think it could be a formatting error when adding a third one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you're using so many parenthesis in that second example, but this should work:

```
if ( $('input[name=su_name]').val() == "" || $('select[name=su_family]').val() == "0" || $('input[name=su_abbrev]').val() == "" )
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention @j08691. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

You've used so many redundant `()`, instead you can just do:

```
if ($('input[name=su_name]').val() == "" || $('select[name=su_family]').val() == "0" || $('input[name=su_abbrev]').val() == "") {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Solved. Thank you Felix. I'll tick in 6 minutes